# Adding formula to apex based on condition

Tags: apex

Can someone help me in modifying the below code to include a formula based on the zone field which is on account object

```
public with sharing class OpportunityOrderEntryController {

   /**
    * Medical Production: OpportunityOrderEntryController
    * for Send to Order Entry button, creates a spreadsheet with order data and emails to Order Entry, 
    * and attaches it to a GBD Order Attachments object
    */
    private String status = '';
    private String oppId = null;
    private Boolean isTokyo = false;
    private Boolean maintenanceOnly = false;
    private Opportunity opp = null;
    private List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLines = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    private Blob csvFile = null; 
    private String orderEmail_us = 'gbdorders@gmail.com';
    private String orderEmail_jp = 'jrosenb@gmail.com'; 
    private String orderEmail = '';

    public OpportunityOrderEntryController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        if (opp == null) {
            oppId = stdController.getId();
            opp = [Select Billed_to__c,  Billed_to_acct__c, Shipped_to__c, Shipped_to_acct__c, Sold_To__c, 
                          Sold_to_acct__c, Name, Site_ID__c, Customer_PO__c, Order_type_implementation__c,
                          instructions__c, CurrencyIsoCode, Account.Name, Contract_Terms__c, Payment_Terms__c,
                          Item_Requires_Shipping__c, Incoterms__c, AccountId
                          from Opportunity where Id = :oppId];
            Account acc = [SELECT Id, Zone__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :opp.AccountId ];
            // Commenting code related to Tokyo to create standard spread sheet across all zones
           // if (acc.Zone__c == 'FTYO') isTokyo = true;
            status = 'Opportunity ' + oppId + ' from getId';
        } 
        if (oppId == null) {
            opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
            if (opp != null) oppId = opp.Id;
            status = 'Opportunity ' + oppId + ' from getRecord';
        }                   
        String mo = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('maint');
        if ((mo != null) && (mo == '1')) maintenanceOnly = true;
    }

    public void setOpportunity(Opportunity r) { 
        opp = r; 
        oppId = opp.Id;
    }

    public String getStatus() { return status; }

    public void checkStatus() {  }

    public void setMaintenanceOnly(Boolean m) { maintenanceOnly = m; }  

    public Boolean isMaintenanceOnly() { return maintenanceOnly; }  

    private void getLines() {
        if (oppId != null) {
            if (maintenanceOnly)
                oppLines = [Select Id, OpportunityId, PricebookEntryId, Quantity, Unit_Sell_Price__c, TotalPrice, UnitPrice,
                                   Product_Family__c, Description, CurrencyIsoCode, PriceBookEntry.Product2.Description,
                                   PriceBookEntry.Product2.ProductCode, PriceBookEntry.Product2.FTYO_Product_Code__c
                              From OpportunityLineItem 
                             where OpportunityId = :oppId and Product_Category__c = 'Annual Maintenance'];
            else
                oppLines = [Select Id, OpportunityId, PricebookEntryId, Quantity, Unit_Sell_Price__c, TotalPrice, UnitPrice,
                                   Product_Family__c, Description, CurrencyIsoCode, PriceBookEntry.Product2.Description,
                                   PriceBookEntry.Product2.ProductCode, PriceBookEntry.Product2.FTYO_Product_Code__c
                              From OpportunityLineItem 
                             where OpportunityId = :oppId and Product_Category__c != 'Annual Maintenance'];
        }   
    }

    public PageReference action() {
        if (opp == null) {
            status = 'Opportunity not found';
            return null;
        }
        getLines();
       //if (isTokyo) {
           // csvFile = createFileJapan();
          //  orderEmail = orderEmail_jp;
      //  } 
      //  else {
            csvFile = createFile();
            orderEmail = orderEmail_us;            
      //  }
        System.debug('## isTokyo? ' + isTokyo + ' emailTo=' + orderEmail);
        if (csvFile != null) {
            sendEmail();
            createAttachment();
            status = 'Spreadsheet created, attached and sent';
        }
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference maintAction() {
        setMaintenanceOnly(true);
        return action();
    }

    public PageReference done() {
        if (opp != null) {
            PageReference reto = new PageReference('/' + oppId); 
            reto.setRedirect(true);
            return reto;
        }               
        return null;
    }

    private Blob createFile() {
        if (opp == null) {
            status = 'Failed to create spreadsheet - no Opportunity';
            return null;
        }
        status = 'Creating Spreadsheet...';
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();
        lines.add('"Bill To",' + deNullQuote(opp.Billed_to_acct__c)  + ',' + deNull(opp.Billed_to__c) + ',,,\n');
        lines.add('"Sold To",' + deNullQuote(opp.Sold_to_acct__c)    + ',' + deNull(opp.Sold_To__c) + 
                  ',,"Order Type",' + deNullQuote(opp.Order_type_implementation__c) + '\n');
        lines.add('"Ship To",' + deNullQuote(opp.Shipped_to_acct__c) + ',' + deNull(opp.Shipped_to__c) + 
                  ',,"Opportunity Name",' + deNull(opp.Name) + '\n'); 
        lines.add('"Site ID",' + deNullQuote(opp.Site_ID__c) + ','+ deNullQuote(opp.Account.Name) + 
                  ',,"Customer PO#",' + deNull(opp.Customer_PO__c) + '\n');
        lines.add('"Instructions",' + deNullQuote(opp.Instructions__c) + ',,,,\n');
        lines.add('"Quantity","Cat No.","Description","Net Price","Extended Net Price","Product Category"\n');  
        for (OpportunityLineItem i : oppLines) {
            String descr = i.Description;
            if (i.Description == null) 
                descr = i.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Description;    
            else
                descr = i.Description;
            lines.add(deNull(i.Quantity) + ',' + 
                      deNullQuote(i.PriceBookEntry.Product2.FTYO_Product_Code__c) + ',' + 
                      deNull(descr) + ',' + 
//                    deNull(i.Unit_Sell_Price__c) + ',' + 
                      deNull(i.UnitPrice) + ',' + 
                      deNull(i.TotalPrice) + ',' +
                      deNull(i.Product_Family__c) + ',' +
                      deNull(i.CurrencyIsoCode) + '\n');    
        }
        lines.add('"Terms",' + deNullQuote(opp.Payment_Terms__c) + ',' + deNullQuote(opp.Contract_Terms__c) + ',,,\n');
        String allLines = '';
        for (String s : lines) { allLines += s; }
        status = 'Spreadsheet Created';
        return Blob.valueOf(allLines);                    
    }

    private void sendEmail() {
        status = 'Sending email to ' + orderEmail;
        String subject = 'Ready to Book: ' + opp.Name;
        String body = 'An order is ready to book.  Details attached.\n' + 
                      URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + oppId +
//                    'https://na8.salesforce.com/' + oppId +
                      '\n\nSite: ' + opp.Account.Name + 
                      '\nBill To: ' + opp.Billed_to__c;

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment att = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        att.setContentType('text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        att.setFilename('opp-' + oppId + '.csv');
        att.setBody(csvFile);

        String[] emailTo = new String[]{ orderEmail };
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { att });
        email.setSubject( subject );
        email.setToAddresses( emailTo );
        email.setPlainTextBody( body ); 
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        status = 'Email Sent';
    }

    private void createAttachment() {
        status = 'Attaching Spreadsheet...';
        GBD_Order_Attachments__c oat = new GBD_Order_Attachments__c();
        oat.Opportunity__c = oppId;
        String oatName = 'Order Entry: ' + opp.Name;
        if (oatName.length() > 80) oatName = oatName.substring(0,80);
        oat.Name = oatName;
        oat.Document_Type__c = 'Order Entry Spreadsheet';
        insert oat;

        Attachment a = new Attachment();
        a.ParentId = oat.Id; // oppId;
        a.Name = 'opp-' + oppId + '.csv';
        a.Description = 'Order Entry: ' + opp.Name;
        a.ContentType = 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8';
//      a.Body = Blob.valueOf(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(csvFile));
        a.Body = csvFile;
        insert a;
        status = 'Spreadsheet attached to "Order Entry: ' + opp.Name + '"';

    }

    private String deNull(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            return '""';
        else 
            return s.escapeCsv();       
    }

    private String deNullQuote(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            return '""';
        else 
            return '"' + s + '"';       
    }

    private String deNull(Decimal s) {
        return s.toPlainString();
    }

    private String deNull(Double s) {
        return ('' + s).escapeCsv();
    }

    private String deNull(Integer s) {
        return ('' + s).escapeCsv();
    }       

    private String deNull(Long s) {
        return ('' + s).escapeCsv();
    }       
}
```

[image: Need to modify the spreadsheet as per the screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please cut this code down to the minimum needed to illustrate your issue, show us what you've implemented so far, and help us understand what you need help solving. SFSE doesn't provide code for requirements, but we're very happy to help with specific issues.

Comment: I could't find any documentation on how to add excel formula in apex code, below is what i modified but couldn't get to use the formula as per the image   lines.add('"Quantity","Cat No.","Description","Net Price","Extended Net Price","FTYO Net Price","Product Category"\n');

Comment: You cannot add an Excel formula in Apex code. You'd need to work with an Apex developer to have that implemented for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write your code for you, but there are three main things you need to do:

1. Add the Zone field to the Opportunity query.

This will look a bit like this:

```
opp = [Select Billed_to__c,  Billed_to_acct__c, Shipped_to__c, Shipped_to_acct__c, Sold_To__c 
   Account.Zone__c //.... other fields (I don't know the dev name of your zone field)
```

2. Add a header for the list of products you are about to generate.

This will be conditional of course on the zone field:

```
lines.add('"Quantity","Cat No.","Description","Net Price","Extended Net Price","FTYO Net Price","Product Category"\n');  
//or add the same lines without the FTYO price if zone is not FTYO
```

3. Add the price itself inside the product loop.

This will be between total price and product family:

```
deNull(i.TotalPrice) + ',' +
//new FTYO price
deNull(i.TotalPrice*.085) + ',' +
deNull(i.Product_Family__c) + ',' +
```

The last two items are both conditional on the zone being FTYO... so you need to check this both when making the header items and the line items. Something like:

```
if (opp.Account.Zone__c == 'FTYO'){
  //do your ftyo stuff
}
```